# does not open the images from the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

The images are not displayed, the files in the source folder are fine, and it does not mark any type of error on the screen, everything else is shown except the image.This is the code of the chapter.php, the part inside the foreach is the one that does not show the image. I do not put the connection, because if it connects with the other functions

```
<?php 
   $hoja = new Mangas();
   $hojas = $hoja->hojas($_GET['id']);

   !$_GET ? header('location: capitulo.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'&pagina=1') : '';
   $nFilas = $hoja->numeroFilas();  //cuenta las paginas existentes
   $x = $_GET['pagina']-1; //Estable el rango
   $pagina = $hoja->getLink($x,$_GET['id']); //Proporciona el numero de paginas del manga

?>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 margen">
           
           <div class="cover" align="center">
               <h1><?php echo $hojas['numeroCap']; ?></h1>
               <?php foreach ($pagina as $pagina): ?>
               <img src="img/capitulos/<?php echo $pagina['hoja']; ?>" class="img-responsive"><!--Expulsa eel el link con respecto a la pagina-->
               <?php endforeach ?>
               
           </div>
           <div align="center">
               <span class="btn btn-info <?php echo $_GET['pagina']<=1 ? 'disabled' : '' ?>"><a href="capitulo.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']-1; ?>">Prev</a></span>
               <span class="btn btn-info <?php echo $_GET['pagina']>=$nFilas ? 'disabled' : '' ?>"><a href="capitulo.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']+1; ?>">Next</a></span>
           </div>
               
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

the public function leaf is to the sentence that connects with the database and should bring the images

```
<?php 
include_once 'conexion.php';
   class Mangas extends Conexion {
       public function Mangas(){
           parent::__construct();
       }
       public function mangaUsuario(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga ORDER BY manga.id ASC";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function directorio($empieza,$tamanoPaginas){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga ORDER BY manga.id ASC LIMIT $empieza,$tamanoPaginas";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function numeroMangas(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->rowCount();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function mangaUsuarios($id){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga WHERE id = '$id'";
           $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function listaCap(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulosmanga ORDER BY capitulosmanga.id DESC LIMIT 10";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function sideBarList(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga ORDER BY manga.id DESC LIMIT 5";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       
       public function subirPortada($manga,$sinopsis,$sinopsisCorta,$imagen,$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5,$a6){
           if($imagen['imagen']['name']<=5000000) {
               if ($imagen['imagen']['type']=="image/jpeg" || $imagen['imagen']['type']=="image/png" || $imagen['imagen']['type']=="image/gif") {
               
                   //ruta imagen
                   $carpeta_destino = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/manga/img/portadas/";
                   //mover imagen del directorio temporal a directorio escogido
                   move_uploaded_file($imagen['imagen']['tmp_name'], $carpeta_destino.$imagen['imagen']['name']);
               }
           }
           $sql = "INSERT INTO manga(nombre, portada,sinopsis,sinopsisCorta,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6) VALUES (:nombre, :portada,:sinopsis,:sinopsisCorta,:A1,:A2,:A3,:A4,:A5,:A6)";
           $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
           $statement->execute(array(':nombre' => $manga, ':portada' => $imagen['imagen']['name'],':sinopsis' => $sinopsis,':sinopsisCorta' => $sinopsisCorta,':A1' => $a1,':A2' => $a2,':A3' => $a3,':A4' => $a4,':A5' => $a5,':A6' => $a6));
           header('location: ../_admin/panel.php');
       }
       public function subirHojas($numeroCap,$numeroVol,$hojas,$mangaRel){//metodo con parametros del formulario
           
           if(isset($hojas["file"])){//condicional para saber si hay imagenes
               for ($i=0; $i <count($hojas['file']['name']) ; $i++) { //bucle para recorrer todas imagenes
                   $file = $hojas['file']; //array de todas la imagenes
                   $nombre = $file['name'][$i]; // nombre de la imagen
                   $tipo = $file['type'][$i]; // tipo de imagen
                   $size = $file['size'][$i]; //tamaño de la imagen
                   $ruta_temp = $file['tmp_name'][$i]; //ruta tamporales de la imagen
                   $carpeta = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/manga/img/capitulos/"; //ruta personalizada
                   if ($tipo != 'image/jpeg' && $tipo != 'image/jpg' && $tipo != 'image/png' && $tipo != 'image/png') {
                       echo $reporte .= "<p>Error: ".$nombre." no es una iamgen.</p>";//condicional para validar el tipo deimagen
                   }else if($size > 5000000){
                       echo $reporte .= "<p>El tamaño del archivo excede el maximo permitido.</p>";//condicional para validadr el tamaño deimagen
                   }else{
                       $src = $carpeta.$nombre;
                       move_uploaded_file($ruta_temp, $src);//mandamos la imagen al directorio propuesto
                       
                   }
                   $sql = "INSERT INTO capitulos(hoja, pagina, hojaRel) VALUES (:hoja, :pagina, :hojaRel)";//consulta para la insersion de registro a la base de datos
                   $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
                   $page = $i +1;
                   $statement->execute(array(':hoja' => $nombre,':pagina' => $page, ':hojaRel' => $mangaRel));                 
               }
               $sql = "INSERT INTO capitulosmanga(numeroCap, numeroVol, mangaRel) VALUES (:numeroCap, :numeroVol, :mangaRel)";//consulta para la insersion de registro a la base de datos
                   $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
                   $statement->execute(array(':numeroCap' => $numeroCap, ':numeroVol' => $numeroVol, ':mangaRel' => $mangaRel));
               echo "<p>Sus imagenes se subieron exitosamente.</p>";//respues devuelta por aJAX
           }
       }
       public function URLCapitulo($id){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulosmanga WHERE capitulosmanga.mangaRel = '$id' ORDER BY capitulosmanga.numeroCap DESC";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function hojas($id){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulos,capitulosmanga WHERE capitulos.hojaRel='$id' AND capitulosmanga.id = '$id'";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function getLink($x,$id){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulos,capitulosmanga WHERE capitulos.hojaRel='$id' AND capitulosmanga.id = '$id' LIMIT $x,1";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function numeroFilas(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulos";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->rowCount();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function eliminarManga($id){
           $this->base->query("DELETE FROM manga WHERE id='$id'");
           header('location: ../_admin/panel.php');
       }
   }
   
   
?>
```

I have to omit the part of the html code, the meta, js and others

Comment: this site is only for questions in English, you can post on https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries